# Windows Server 2008R2 - Programs can connect on localhost but not communicate

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, localhost

I'm having a strange issue with my home server running Windows Server 2008R2. Programs such as the Filezilla Admin interface and MySQL Workbench are able to establish a connection to the server. But once connected they can't authenticate.

While initially thinking the problem was with Filezilla I found this thread:
https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=45851

I tried connecting to Filezilla over telnet like he did. It gives a response but it's incredibly slow. Like 80's dial-up slow. Only prints a few characters every minute.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Even though you found an answer to your question, as written the question is *too broad* for others to know if the problem they're having is the same as yours. Please [edit] your question to narrow the problem down and please keep in mind any material you link can become unavailable, so the essential parts of the link should be included in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course I find the answer less than 5 minutes after asking the question. Posting the answer here for others' future reference.

Seems it was caused by a misconfiguation made with the following tool:
https://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php

I loaded a backup of the original TCP/IP settings, applied them and rebooted and now I'm able to connect just fine with MySQL workbench.

If you're having the same problem and haven't used SpeedGuide's TCP/IP Optimizer then it could possibly be another program, or virus, that's messed with the TCP/IP stack in the registry.